# Rails route, show all elements on the same page

Tags: ruby, custom-routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1, mongoid4

I need to show all my elements on the same page.
In routes:

```
  namespace :nourishment do
   resources :diets do
     resources :nourishment_meals, :controller => 'meals'
     get 'nourishment_meals/show_all_meals' => 'meals#show_all_meals', as: "show_all_meals"
   end
  end
```

which will generate:

```
nourishment_diet_nourishment_meals_path  GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals(.:format)     nourishment/meals#index
POST     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals(.:format)     nourishment/meals#create
new_nourishment_diet_nourishment_meal_path   GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/new(.:format)     nourishment/meals#new
edit_nourishment_diet_nourishment_meal_path  GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/:id/edit(.:format)    nourishment/meals#edit
nourishment_diet_nourishment_meal_path   GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/:id(.:format)     nourishment/meals#show
PATCH    /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/:id(.:format)     nourishment/meals#update
PUT  /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/:id(.:format)     nourishment/meals#update
DELETE   /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/:id(.:format)     nourishment/meals#destroy


[**THIS**]
    nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path     GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/show_all_meals(.:format)  nourishment/meals#show_all_meals
```

The problem, when I do this:

```
<%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path, :class=>"button green" %>
```

This error raise:

```
Problem:


Problem:
  Document(s) not found for class NourishmentMeal with id(s) show_all_meals.
Summary:
  When calling NourishmentMeal.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): show_all_meals ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: show_all_meals.
Resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
```

---

The error is here, on my meals_controller.rb

```
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_nourishment_meal
      @nourishment_diet = NourishmentDiet.find(params[:diet_id])
     [***HERE***] @nourishment_meal = @nourishment_diet.meals.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Method:

```
  def show_all_meals
    puts "This word does not appear"
  end
```

---

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should be passing `diet_id`.Can you post your `show_all_meals` method?

Comment: I decided to make on Diet Controller.
The Diet controller, dont require the meal_id.

Thanks all
<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route below expects a `:diet_id`. A `diet` instance has to be provided as an argument for this path to call corresponding action.

> ```
> nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path     GET     /nourishment/diets/:diet_id/nourishment_meals/show_all_meals(.:format)  nourishment/meals#show_all_meals
> ```

This should be changed:

```
<%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path, :class=>"button green" %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path(diet), :class=>"button green" %>
```

Notice the argument `(diet)` above.

Comment: <%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path(@nourishment_diet.id), :class=>"button green" %>

The same error

Comment: @IgorOliveiraAntonio It seems that it is taking parameter value as `"show_all_meals"`. Can you check the development log and provide the `params` hash when you click that link?

Comment: Yeah man, the params:

{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"nourishment/meals", "diet_id"=>"5388c25e70726505f4050000", "id"=>"show_all_meals"}

Comment: Thanks man, for your quention, i decided to do in my diet controller.
The new routes:

get 'nourishment/diets/:id/show_all_meals' => 'nourishment/diets#show_all_meals', as: "show_all_meals"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass diet_id parameter in params. You should try something like this: `<%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path(@diet.id), :class=>"button green" %>`. `@diet.id` is just an example, use whatever works for your application.

Comment: <%= link_to "Show all meals", nourishment_diet_show_all_meals_path(@nourishment_diet.id), :class=>"button green" %>

The same error =(